# c3js legend beside each Bar

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, c3.js

I am working on a stacked bar chart with c3js. How can i show the bar values with the legend permanently beside each bar? normally they are only in the tooltip.

**I attached a mockup to show you what i mean:**
[image: Bar Chart Mockup]

**What i have so far ([see my jsfiddle for a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/NONNNNN/vL23rbkz/7/)):**

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30],
            ['data2', 130],
            ['data3', 230],
            
            ['data4', 120],
            ['data5', 50],
            ['data6', 20],
            
            ['data7', 30],
            ['data8', 130],
            ['data9', 230]
        ],
        type: 'bar',
        groups: [
            ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'],
            ['data4', 'data5', 'data6'],
            ['data7', 'data8', 'data9']
        ]
    },
    grid: {
        y: {
            lines: [{value:0}]
        }
    }
});
```

I'm happy for every input / solution to get my problem solved :)

Cheers,
Marco

Comment: Did you end up using the answer below, I have the same type of requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it's possible but it's not pure c3.

The way I do it is using d3.selectAll("c3-bar") in order to select all "path" elements that indicate our bars.

Then i'd add d3 code to insert a text element by the side of each bar
Something like

```
    d3.selectAll(".c3-bars").insert("text").text(function(d){
console.info(d);
return "123";
}).attr("x","0").attr("y","50").attr("font-size","13").attr("stroke","red");
```

**note that this is not hte code that does exactly what you need but it should give you an idea on where to go**

Note that you will have to add this code to .onrender() function in the chart definition, in order to have it rendered every time.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michaelrodov/1495fatL/2/)